# Flash CC Make layer invisible by using the code?

Tags: flash, 2d, adobe

I am trying to make a 2D shooter game and I need to make the bullet image invisible while it is not being shot.
Is this possible? If not, is there any other way I could make a bullet?

**Notice:** My bullet is an PNG image, not a rectangle or a sphere.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the image in a MovieClip, you can access it via ActionScript and do something like:

```
bullet.visible = false;
```